# In the process of calculating the limit, why is this substitution equal

Tags: limits

On the limit of quotient, I know that infinity is comparable.
Functions and infinity are too abstract for me,I don't know how to understand it.

Excuse me for taking a screenshot of an answer in the forum.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9T2E.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9T2E.png)(There is my red mark in the picture)

### $\lim_{y\to\infty}{f^{-1}(8y)\over y^{1/3}}=2\lim_{y\to\infty}{f^{-1}(8y)\over(8y)^{1/3}}=2\lim_{z\to\infty}{f^{-1}(z)\over z^{1/3}}\ $ $Q=\lim_{z\to\infty}{f^{-1}(z)\over z^{1/3}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}{f^{-1}\bigl(f(x)\bigr)\over \bigl(f(x)\bigr)^{1/3}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}{x\over 2x\bigl(1+{3\over 8x^2}\bigr)^{1/3}}={1\over2}\ .$

### This is a copy command, and I don't know how to handle it

### Question :Why is the above replacement equivalent? What can we learn from？

A better description of the problem:

$\lim_{ab\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a}{b}=1$

$\lim_{ab\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(a)}{f(b)}=1/2$

I don't know if there is any necessary connection above

If so,what will be the result?

## ab is another number and $\lim_{ab\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a}{b}=2$

---

---

---

Comment: "This is a copy command, and I don't know how to handle it": what ??????

Comment: Sorry, don’t be angry, I don’t know how to make the formula bigger and how to write something under lim instead of on the right

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply the numerator and the denominator by 2, you get $$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(8y)}{y^{1/3}} = \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2 \cdot f^{-1}(8y)}{2\cdot y^{1/3}}$$ And because $2 = 8^{1/3}$, it simplifies to $$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(8y)}{y^{1/3}} = 2 \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(8y)}{8^{1/3}\cdot y^{1/3}} = 2\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f^{-1}(8y)}{(8y)^{1/3}}$$
Then you can just substitute $z = 8y$, which clearly approaches infinity when $y \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thank you,I am learning slowly, but I don't have a deep concept.I noticed that y tends to infinity, even if 8y is replaced by z, it goes to infinity,But I think this is 8 times the infinity. Is such a replacement possible?

Comment: Maybe I noticed that the replacement of z is 8y, which means that their replacement growth rate is the same and will not break this limit. I want to know all feasible explanations.

Comment: Even if y tends to infinity, assuming that the denominator is 8y and the numerator is 4y, they all tend to infinity. I can't treat them all as z. This is my question.